# Simulation of SVM PWM

Tags: pwm, power-electronics, simulation

I have developed a simulation of the space vector modulation (svm) for standard two level three phase voltage source inverter.

[image]

The simulation is created in the Scilab/Xcos with usage of C block (i.e. generic block which can be "filled" with code in C language)

[image]

The first results seems to be correct. Please see the below given outcomes of the simulation. The simulation suppose the carrier frequency \$f_c = 1000\,\mathrm{Hz}\$ and modulation
frequency \$f_m = 60\,\mathrm{Hz}\$.

- Components of the reference space vector at the input to the SVM block (normalized by the dc link voltage \$V_{dc}=564\,\mathrm{V}\$)

[image]

- Duty cycles for the upper transistors (S11, S21, S31) in the inverter along with the carrier signal

[image]

- Firing signals for the upper transistors (S11, S21, S31) in the inverter

[image]

Nevertheless I would like to be hundred percent sure that the svm algorithm works correctly. I would like to ask you for assesment of the above given waveforms. Do you think that my implementation works correctly? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation seems to be correct and working properly. It is difficult to see from your waveforms alone if you're having a mistake in your SVM implementation, since you're not showing it.

There are several ways to implement SVM (either using the conventional way of calculating the Dwell times that form the space vector or using a conventional Sine-PWM carrier based implementation with a superimposed common-mode offset). If you are familiar with both implementations, you could conduct a FFT of both and see if their spectral behavior matches. If so, you can gain at least some sort of confidence.

Good luck.